# Show all records from table Zend Framework

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, tablerow

I already know how fetch information from database and show them in view, but I don't know how calculate table row in Zend Framework 
 in controller , I've connected to database and fetch information and in view of this controller , I've used to use static value. I want to show information as long as their exists.

**Controller:**

```
.
.
.
        $AModel = new Model_A();
        $select = $AModel->fetchAll($AModel->select()->where('user_id = ?', $part_mail ));  
        $this->view->rowArray = $select->toArray();
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($select);
        echo $num_rows;
    .
    .
    .
```

**View:**

```
<?php 
            for ($i=0 ; $i<=3; ++$i)
            {

                    print  '<tr><td>uid:'. ($this->rowArray[$i]['uid']).'</td>';
                    print  '<td>online_status:'. ($this->rowArray[$i]['online_status']).'</td>';
                    print  '<td>failed_logins:'. ($this->rowArray[$i]['failed_logins']).'</td></tr>';
            }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$args=array(
        'host' =>'localhost',
        'username' =>'root',
        'password' =>'',
        'dbname' =>'dbname');

$db = Zend_Db::Factory('PDO_MYSQL',$args);
$select = $db->select()
             ->from('table_name')
             ->where('user_id = ?', $part_mail )
$stmt = $db->query($select);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
**Controller:**

```
$AModel = new Model_A();
$select = $AModel->fetchAll($AModel->select()->where('user_id = ?', $part_mail )); 
        $rowCount = count($select);         
        if ($rowCount > 0) {
            echo "found $rowCount rows";
            $this->view->rowCount = count($select);
            $this->view->rowArray = $select->toArray();
        } else {
        echo 'no rows matched the query';
        }
```

**View:**

```
<?php 

            for ($i=0 ; $i<=$this->rowCount; ++$i)
            {

                    print  '<tr><td>uid:'. ($this->rowArray[$i]['uid']).'</td>';
                    print  '<td>online_status:'. ($this->rowArray[$i]['online_status']).'</td>';
                    print  '<td>failed_logins:'. ($this->rowArray[$i]['failed_logins']).'</td></tr>';
            }?>
```

Comment: Why not send `$select` to view and then use `foreach($select as $row)`?

Comment: please tell me about detail of this answer@Volvox

Comment: if `Model_A` extends `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract` (and it should) then `fetchAll()` returns `Zend_Db_Table_Rowset_Abstract` which can be used like arrays. So you can do `$this->view->select = $select` and in view `$this->select->count()` to get items count and `foreach ($this->select as $row){ echo $row->uid }`  (each $row is `Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract` which can be useful in many ways but this is another story)